# Populando Var colors com dados do banco

Tags: php, javascript

Agora está populando apenas com uma matrícula, deve ser algo com meu while.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <!-- Ignite UI Required Combined CSS Files -->
    <link href="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2017.1/latest/css/themes/infragistics/infragistics.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2017.1/latest/css/structure/infragistics.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/modernizr/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Ignite UI Required Combined JavaScript Files -->
    <script src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2017.1/latest/js/infragistics.core.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2017.1/latest/js/infragistics.lob.js"></script>

            <meta name="author" content="Clube dos Geeks">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">           

    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <style>        
        .combo-label {margin-bottom:.5em;}
       </style>
<h4 class="combo-label">Selecione as matrículas:</h4>
<div id="checkboxSelectCombo"></div>

   <?php
include 'conexao.php';
$sel= "select matricula FROM usuarios WHERE ativo = 1";
$query = mysql_query ($sel, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());

?>

<script>
    <?php
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{ ?>
    var colors = [
        { Name: "<?php echo $result['matricula']; ?>" },
    ];
<?php } ?>

    $(function () {

        $("#checkboxSelectCombo").igCombo({
            width: 300,
            dataSource: colors,
                textKey: "Name",
                valueKey: "Name",
                multiSelection: {
                    enabled: true,
                    showCheckboxes: true
                },
                dropDownOrientation: "bottom"
            });

        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta. Não consegui executar aqui pelo site, mas se salvar e tentar jogar no local host ele roda de boas. Queria ajuda pra depois de fazer o select jogar no color ali as matrículas.

Comment: Tem de incluir o código php que está a utilizar, porque a sua pergunta é maioritariamente sobre php e não javascript. Apenas acontece que os valores que o php vai gerar vão calhar dentro de um bloco de javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O teu problema é que estas a fazer um loop onde esta sempre a declarar a mesma variável, o que leva a só teres um valor. Tenta fazer da seguinte maneira:

**PHP**

```
$colors = [];
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $colors[] = $result['matricula'];
}

//converte ARRAY PHP para json
$colors = json_encode($colors);
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
    var colors = <?= $colors; ?>
</script>
```

porem isto é má pratica.
Notei no teu código que ainda estas a usar, `mysql_*`, o que é vulnerável a vários ataques e nas versões futuras do PHP será removida.

Aconselho a usares [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) ou [MYSQLI](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php) e tenta no máximo separar php e javascript.

Comment: Obrigado pelos conselhos, estou a aprender na prática.